Use of correspondence theorem for groups to prove that $o(N) = 2$
Let $G$ be a group and $H \triangleleft G$ simple such that $[G : H] = 2$. I have to prove that if $N \neq \{1\}$, $N \triangleleft G$ and $N \cap H = \{1\}$ then $o(N) = 2$.
I know by third isomorphism theorem that $H \triangleleft NH \leq G$ and $NH/H \cong N/N \cap H \cong N$. I'd like to say that $NH/H \leq G/H$, but I'm not really sure if that's true by correspondence theorem.

Note that $G = NH$.

You don't really need the correspondence theorem. Assume that $a, b \in N \setminus \{1\}$ and consider the images $aH$ and $bH$ in the coset space  $G/H$. As $[G:H] = 2$, we know that $G/H$ comprises the two sets $H$ and $G\setminus H$. As neither $a$ nor $b$ is in $H$, we can only have $aH = bH = G \setminus H$. Now as $G \setminus H$ is a coset of $H$ in $G$, it is equal to $xH$ where $x$ is any of its elements. But that means that $a = xa'$ and $b = xb'$ for some $x$ and some $a', b' \in H$. So $a^{-1}b \in N$ (as $a \in N$ and $b\in N$) and also $a^{-1}b = a'^{-1}x^{-1}xb' = a'^{-1}b' \in H$ (as $a'\in H$ and $b\in H$). So $a^{-1}b \in N \cap H = \{1\}$, i.e., $a^{-1}b = 1$, implying $a = b$. We have shown that $N$ has only one element other than $1$, hence $o(N) = 2$.
Aside: the above argument does not require the assumption that $N$ is normal, nor does it use the fact that, because $[G: H] = 2$, $H$ must be normal. I can't think of a slick way of using the normality of $H$ or $N$ to give a shorter proof (or one that makes any good use of the correspondence theorem).

$H$ is necessarily normal (as is any index 2 subgroup) since its (left and right) cosets are $H$ and $G\backslash H$.

@krm2233: yes, of course. I know that but I don't think the OP does and I didn't want to overegg my answer. The proof does not require this fact, it just happens to follow from the assumptions.

I guess it is just a question of semantics then, apologies. Since the hypotheses require that $H$ is index 2, and index 2 subgroups are (fairly trivially) necessarily normal, I would be inclined to say that the hypotheses require $H$ to be normal. On the other hand, the requirement for $N$ to be normal is superfluous (and I agree, I don't see any obvious argument using normality of $N$ which would give a simpler proof of that special case).

@krm2233: no need to apologise: thank you for making a point that may well be of interest to the OP and others: I should have added something about that in the aside (and have now done so).

Here's an alternative argument which makes explicit use of the fact, already pointed out in Rob Arthan's answer, that as $[G:H]=2$, the subgroup $H$ must be normal, with both its left and right cosets being equal to $H$ and its complement, $H^c$. We may thus form the quotient group $G/H$ and we write $q \colon G \to G/H$ for the quotient homomorphism, that is the map given by $q(g)=gH$ $(\forall g \in G$).
Now if $p\colon N \to G/H$ denotes the restriction of $q$ to $N$, then since the kernel of $q$ is $H$, the kernel of $p$ is $N\cap H = \{e\}$. It follows that $p\colon N \to G/H$ is injective, and hence $|N|\leq |G/H|=2$.
